# C++ replacing character in strings

Tags: c++

Im currently trying to capitalize the character 'i' but only if it's by itself

this is the code i have

```
int main()
{
    string textMessage = "Yesterday’s Doctor Who broadcast made me 
    laugh and cry in the same episode! i can only wonder what the 
     Doctor will get into next. My family and i are huge fans.";


replace(textMessage.begin(), textMessage.end(), 'i', 'I');

 cout << textMessage;

}
```

my output is

`Yesterday’s Doctor Who broadcast made me laugh and cry In the same epIsode! I can only wonder what the Doctor wIll get Into next. My famIly and I are huge fans.`

this is the output i want

`Yesterday’s Doctor Who broadcast made me laugh and cry in the same episode! I can only wonder what the Doctor will get into next. My family and I are huge fans.`

Comment: Take out a piece of paper, and write down, in short sentences, a logical process for determining whether the letter `i` in the string is by itself, or is a part of a word. That shouldn't take more than a minute or so. ... Ok, time's up! Now simply take what you've written down and directly translate into code. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the replace function you will have to traverse through the string and check for only those 'i' which are preceded and succeeded by a whitespace and replace them with 'I'. I guess the following code segment would do what you are trying to achieve :-

```
for (int iTraverse = 0; iTraverse< textMessage.length(); iTraverse++)
{
    if (textMessage[iTraverse] == 'i' && textMessage[iTraverse-1] == ' ' && textMessage[iTraverse+1]     == ' ')
    {
        textMessage[iTraverse] = 'I';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i needed

Comment: mention it not,but you should have done this by yourself rather than relying on others as it wasn't something very difficult to achieve :)

Comment: I definitely understand where you were coming from and I would rather figure it out myself but I the thing was I wasn't looking for the exact answer I just needed to know the function I could have figured everything else out

Comment: Ok,i get your point..!  :)

Answer (score 0):

A letter by itself is a letter that is surrounded by whitespace, not other letters. A letter by itself is also easy to account for because it is always surrounded by whitespace.

```
replace(textMessage.begin(), textMessage.end(), ' i ', ' I ');
```

If you change the code in your program to this (it replaces i's that have whitespace with uppercase I's) it should work.

Comment: ive tried it and had no sucees

Comment: What was your output?

Comment: All of the 'i' stayed lowercase